# How do you call a function built in Angular 2 in ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, function, ionic-framework, ionic2, typescript2.0

I am trying to call a function that I wrote in typescript/Angular 2 inside my ionic 2 tab. I am very new to typescript, so do not exactly know how it works.

When  I am trying to call the function, the console gives an error saying that the randomise() function I wrote is not a function...

[This is a JSFiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/dow3ejb8/1/) where i put my code. The 'cards' part works flawless, it only concerns the randomise function for me.
HTML:

```
<button fab class="card-subtitle">{{randomise(100,10000) | currency :'USD' : true}}</button>
```

TS:

```
export class randomNumber {

    public number: number;

    constructor (min: number, max: number){
        this.randomise(min, max)
    }  
    randomise(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your random number class is not a part of your page/component. Create an instance of the class and call it. So new randomNumber().randomise(0,100) will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @misha130 says, you get that error because the `randomise(...)` method is not part of the same component where you're trying to call it.

I'd change your class a little bit, like this:

```
export class RandomNumber {

    constructor (){ }

    public randomise(min, max): number {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
}
```

Instead of calling the `randomise` method in the constructor, you can call it directly from an instance like we're going to see next.

You can do something like this in the html code:

```
<button fab class="card-subtitle">{{getRandomNumber(100,10000) | currency :'USD' : true}}</button>
```

And then in your component, include a method that calls the `randomise` method from an instance of the `RandomNumber` class

```
// your page component

// Variable to hold the instance of the randomNumber class  
randomNumberInstance: any;
result: number;

constructor(){
    // your code...
    this.randomNumberInstance = new RandomNumber();
}

public getRandomNumber(value1: number, value2: number):number {
    this.result = this.randomNumberInstance.randomise(value1, value2);
}
```